# Работа с примитивами WinApi

Tags: winapi, c++

После компиляции выводит "белое" окно. Никаких закрашенных пикселей, линий, и фигур.
То ли рандом не работает.. Кстати, обязательно для того что бы каждый раз генерировались разные случайные числа использовать `srand(time(NULL))`, и подключать `time.h` или можно как то обойтись без этого?

И еще, не совсем понял, зачем использовать совместимый контекст устройства (`hCompatibleDC`)?

Добавил в `WM_PAINT BitBlt`, и все заработало, наверное тупой вопрос, но почему? Почему без этой функции, не окрашиваются пиксели, и линии?

```
BitBlt(hDC,PaintStruct.rcPaint.left,PaintStruct.rcPaint.top,
                       PaintStruct.rcPaint.right,PaintStruct.rcPaint.bottom,
                       hCompatibleDC,
                       PaintStruct.rcPaint.left,PaintStruct.rcPaint.top,SRCCOPY);
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

LRESULT CALLBACK GraphDemoWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message,UINT wParam,LONG lParam )
{
    HDC hDC,hCompatibleDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT PaintStruct;
    RECT Rect;
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap,hCompatibleBitmap;
    HPEN hOldPen;
    static HPEN Pens[5];
    HBRUSH hOldBrush;
    static HBRUSH Brushes[5];
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
                srand(time(NULL));
                for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
                {
                    Pens[i]=(CreatePen(i,1,RGB(rand()%255,rand()%255,rand()%255)));
                    Brushes[i]=(CreateHatchBrush(i,RGB(rand()%255,rand()%255,rand()%255)));
                }
                GetClientRect(hWnd,&Rect);
                hDC=BeginPaint(hWnd,&PaintStruct);
                hCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
                hCompatibleBitmap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC,Rect.right,Rect.bottom);
                hOldBitmap=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(hCompatibleDC,hCompatibleBitmap);
                PatBlt(hCompatibleDC, 0,0,Rect.right,Rect.bottom, PATCOPY);
                for (int i=0;i<=9999;i++)
                {
                    SetPixel(hCompatibleDC,rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom,RGB(rand()%255,rand()%255,rand()%255));
                }
                for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
                {
                    hOldPen=(HPEN)SelectObject(hCompatibleDC,Pens[rand()%4]);
                    MoveToEx(hCompatibleDC,rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom,NULL);
                    LineTo(hCompatibleDC,rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom);
                    SelectObject(hCompatibleDC,hOldPen);
                }
                for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
                {
                    hOldBrush=(HBRUSH)SelectObject(hCompatibleDC,Brushes[rand()%4]);
                    Rectangle(hCompatibleDC,rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom,
                              rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom);
                    Ellipse(hCompatibleDC,rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom,
                              rand()%Rect.right,rand()%Rect.bottom);
                    SelectObject(hCompatibleDC,hOldBrush);
                }
                for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
                    {
                        DeleteObject(Pens[i]);
                        DeleteObject(Brushes[i]);
                    }
                SelectObject(hCompatibleDC,hOldBitmap);
                DeleteObject(hCompatibleBitmap);
                DeleteDC(hCompatibleDC);
                EndPaint(hWnd,&PaintStruct);
                return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,Message,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: Узнал что функция PitBlt как раз и "переносит" из виртуального в реальный контекст, этот вопрос отпал. Time.h "весит" не много, так что с ним проблем тоже нет. Только зачем использовать виртуальный(совместимый) контекст?

Comment: > Добавил в WM_PAINT BitBlt, и все заработало, наверное тупой вопрос, но почему? Почему без этой функции, не окрашиваются пиксели, и линии?

Очевидно, потому что вы рисуете не в самом окне, а в виртуальном графическом контексте. Функция BitBlt как раз и нужна, чтобы перенести изображение в графический контекст окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш вопрос(ы) не до конца понятен, поэтому отвечу, как понял сам.

1)  Без этого `srand(time(NULL))` не обойтись никак, если хотите, чтобы каждый раз генерировались **именно новые** значения. Если же вам нужно получать просто рандомные значения без надобности их новизны, то можно использовать просто:

```
 rand(max) % 0+min; // вроде так =)
```

2) Что делает апишная функция "BitBlt"? Она копирует карту бит из одного графического контекста в другой. Т.е, по сути, функция делает скриншот контекста устройства и копирует его во второй. В вашем случае вот сюда **hDC** копируется вот этот контекст **hCompatibleDC**. Далее вы просто рисуете графические примитивы в том контексте, куда была скопирована карта бит( другого контекста ).

Comment: Я знаю что так получаются именно новые значения, только можно как то их получать не используя time.h? rand() как видно в коде я знаю как использовать. С функцией BitBlt все разъяснили, спасибо.

Comment: К сожалению, но нет! Рандомное значение может получиться только, если один из операторов динамичен, т.е изменяется в рантайме. Это время.

Comment: @Влад Малахин, rand() без предварительного srand() будет выдавать одну и ту же последовательность. Вместо time Вы можете попробовать взять какое-то другое число, не зависящее от программы. 

Координаты мышки, свободное место на диске, количество пакетов, отправленных по сети и т.д. 

На практике проще всего брать время. Только учтите, что программа, запускаемая в цикле (например из скрипта) может получать много раз одно и то же время (в секундах).

Comment: Да, и как это я про координаты мышки забыл только? Но вот только пользователь может её не трогать долгое время, и программа будет выдавать один и тот же резалт...со свободным   местом на диске такая же картина!

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, можно поставить srand() до цикла, программа возьмет один раз координаты мышки, и все время работы программы будут разные числа в рандоме.

Comment: И именно для этой программы, координаты мышки меняются постоянно, тут по обстоятельствам.. Проще конечно взять время, и не париться

Comment: Точно, @Влад. Все берут время. 

Мышка, диск и т.п. - это, очевидно же, шутка.